# Linker error when using cinder and poco

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, poco-libraries, cinder

I'm trying to use libcinder to make some visualizations. In integrating in my existing codebase, I've run into some linker errors that I can't figure out. 
I've boiled the problem down to a minimal example, with the following results:

```
cd /build/src && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/BasicApp.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++   -O3 -DNDEBUG   CMakeFiles/BasicApp.dir/BasicApp.cpp.o  -o ../bin/BasicApp -rdynamic -lPocoUtil -lPocoFoundation
make[2]: Leaving directory '/build'
[100%] Built target BasicApp
make[1]: Leaving directory '/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /build/CMakeFiles 0
```

If don't involve cinder at all, everything works fine, as seen above. if I add my function to the minimal cinder example (BasicApp), I get the following output on compilation:

```
cd /build/src && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/BasicApp.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++   -O3 -DNDEBUG   CMakeFiles/BasicApp.dir/BasicApp.cpp.o  -o ../bin/BasicApp -rdynamic -lPocoUtil -lPocoFoundation /cinder/lib/linux/x86_64/ogl/Release/libcinder.a -lGLU -lGL -lSM -lICE -lX11 -lXext -lXcursor -lXinerama -lXrandr -lXi -lz -lcurl -lfontconfig -lpulse -lmpg123 -lsndfile -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lgstreamer-1.0 -lgstbase-1.0 -lgstapp-1.0 -lgstvideo-1.0 -lgstgl-1.0 /cinder/lib/linux/x86_64//libboost_system.a /cinder/lib/linux/x86_64//libboost_filesystem.a -ldl -lpthread 
CMakeFiles/BasicApp.dir/BasicApp.cpp.o: In function `load_images(std::string, std::string, int, int)':
BasicApp.cpp:(.text+0xca2): undefined reference to `Poco::DirectoryIterator::DirectoryIterator(std::string const&)'
BasicApp.cpp:(.text+0xd57): undefined reference to `Poco::DirectoryIterator::DirectoryIterator(std::string const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
src/CMakeFiles/BasicApp.dir/build.make:118: recipe for target 'bin/BasicApp' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/BasicApp] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/build'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1244: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/BasicApp.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/BasicApp.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/build'
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm assuming that some configuration set in the cinder cmake files is messing things up, but I don't understand why or how to fix it.
This is with gcc version 5.4.0 and cmake version 3.5.1.

Here is a reduced cmake file that has this issue:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(segslam C CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/poco")

find_package(Poco REQUIRED)

#include($ENV{CINDER_PATH}/proj/cmake/configure.cmake)
#set(cinder_DIR $ENV{CINDER_PATH}/${CINDER_LIB_DIRECTORY})
#find_package(cinder REQUIRED PATHS " $ENV{CINDER_PATH}/${CINDER_LIB_DIRECTORY}")



add_executable(BasicApp BasicApp.cpp)

#target_include_directories(BasicApp PUBLIC $ENV{CINDER_PATH}/include)
#target_link_libraries(BasicApp cinder)


target_link_libraries(BasicApp ${Poco_LIBRARIES})

set_target_properties(BasicApp PROPERTIES
    DEBUG_POSTFIX "d"
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin")

install(TARGETS BasicApp RUNTIME DESTINATION bin COMPONENT main)
install(FILES ${srcs} DESTINATION app COMPONENT main)
```

If the commented lines are uncommented, it links in cinder and things break. I'm using a FindPoco.cmake file from [here](https://github.com/astahl/poco-cmake). The cinder cmake files are located [here](https://github.com/cinder/Cinder/tree/master/proj/cmake).

It doesn't seem to matter what the linking order is, and none of the other libraries I'm using have this issue.

Comment: Show us your CMake code.

Comment: @arrowd I've added my cmake code to the question.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that the issue is an ABI mismatch. Cinder ships with precompiled boost libraries that use a gcc version <5.1, which will cause conflicts if you try to use libraries that have been compiled with gcc version >= 5.1.

My fix was to remove the cinder precompiled boost libraries and recompile with the version of boost in the ubuntu repos.

See [this](http://discourse.libcinder.org/t/linker-errors-mongodb-cxx-driver-on-linux/504/8) thread on the cinder discourse for more info.